Do I need to be working on an app to get the API key?
I want to use the API, and I want the higher query limit (I want to scan my inbox every five minutes and then text me the results), but I don't want to have to release an app.
Can I get an API key without ever releasing an app?


Can I get an API key without ever releasing an app?

Yes, you can.
You only need a question (ironically the question you just asked can be used) when your app requires write-access.
Reading your inbox doesn't have that requirement. You need to implement/use Authentication
See also:

I only need a key, what do I do?
Getting "application not configured for implicit grants" error trying to setup website

